# how does jersey instance @Path class?

Tags: java, scala, jersey, synchronization

I want synchronized a specify http request by simple use `synchronized`.
I wonder how many jersey will instance the @Path class. a example class like this:

```
@Path("homepage")
class HomePage {
  @GET
  def index = synchronized {
    ...
  }
}
```

I'm try to synchronized `index` method. The count of jersey instance `HomePage` class is matter of should I use a additional single object as a lock.
If jersey instance multiple `HomePage` I must use another lock object rather then `HomePage` itself,
in contrast, simple `synchronized` is enough as above example.

Answer (score 0):

Jersey create new object for every request. I'm new in Scala, but this code should work:

```
@Path("homepage")
class HomePage {
  private object HomePageLock
  @GET
  def index = { HomePageLock.synchronized { 
     ... 
  } 
}
```

Comment: thanks explain this. by the way, `object` inner scala class is NOT unique.So at this point, put `HomePageLock` at outer of the `HomePage` will fine.